# Can't install captcha plugin on Joomla 1.5.22

Tags: joomla, captcha, joomla1.5

I am on joomla 1.5.22.  I cannot get my captcha/anti-spam to appear on my contact form.

I searched in the backend, no plugin captcha is installed.

I can't even install a new one, I got this error:

> JFolder :: create: Can not create folder Warning ! - The file could
>   not be moved.

This is the url of the site: [site-url](http://www.pompage-degazage-paris.com/nous-contacter)

Comment: Which plugin you wanted to install and what was the version of that plugin. mention all details so that it will be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: i wont to add a captcha or anti-spam to contact form page , i searched in the net i found some free plugin but i can't install any one of them, always there is the error

Comment: Your main problem is that support for Joomla 1.5 ended in 2012 and most extension developers no longer offer Joomla 1.5 versions of their extensions. You may need to migrate to Joomla 3.x to be able to add this functionality. Alternatively, you could ask developers for an older version of their extension or other Joomla web professionals who may have kept older versions of extensions to be able to keep supporting Joomla 1.5 etc. PHP 5.6 is also end of life very soon and hosting companies will eventually drop support for PHP 5.6 and this will be the end for Joomla 1.5 as it won't run on PHP 7.

Comment: This does not sound like a simple fix.  I do want to ask you, though, that when you have Joomla-specific questions would you please write them at Joomla Stack Exchange?  This helps to keep questions flowing and people active/interested.

Comment: It looks more like a folder and permission issue rather than the plugin issue. Check if you have correct tmp and log path in configuration.php and also check if folders have the correct permission.